# MSAL library with powershell for azure devops token cache issue

Tags: powershell, authentication, caching, azure-devops, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL library to fetch token for azure devops.
I am writing powershell script.

Issue is, it is asking to select/relogin if i close the current powershell7 session and reopen again. it is not automatically using get token silently.
its working fine in the same session, it is properly taking token silently, issue comes if i close and reopen the powershell window.
how can I cache in next session also?

```
[string[]] $Scopes = "$adoResourceId/.default";
[Microsoft.Identity.Client.IPublicClientApplication] $app = [Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder]::Create($ClientId).Build();

[ContextHelper]::Account = $app.GetAccountsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult() | Select-Object -First 1
$tokenSource = New-Object System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource
$taskAuthenticationResult = $null
try {
    $AquireTokenParameters = $app.AcquireTokenSilent($Scopes, [ContextHelper]::Account)
    $taskAuthenticationResult = $AquireTokenParameters.ExecuteAsync($tokenSource.Token)
    if ($taskAuthenticationResult.exception.message -like "*errors occurred*") {
        $AquireTokenParameters = $app.AcquireTokenInteractive($Scopes)
        $taskAuthenticationResult = $AquireTokenParameters.ExecuteAsync($tokenSource.Token)
    }
}
catch {
    $AquireTokenParameters = $app.AcquireTokenInteractive($Scopes)
    $taskAuthenticationResult = $AquireTokenParameters.ExecuteAsync($tokenSource.Token)
}
if ($taskAuthenticationResult.Result) {
    $result = $taskAuthenticationResult.Result;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't, the credential will be not cached locally, it is required interactive login when opening a new PowerShell session.

Actually, no need to use such a complex way to get the token for Azure DevOps, you could simply use Azure PowerShell to do that, please follow the steps below.

1. Follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.3.0) to install `Az` powershell module.
2. Use `Connect-AzAccount` to login your user account.
3. Use [`Get-AzAccessToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azaccesstoken?view=azps-6.3.0) to get the token for Azure DevOps, `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798` is the resource id of Azure DevOps.

   `Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798"`

   [image]
4. After login Azure PowerShell, it will store the user context as a `AzureRmContext.json` file in path `~/.azure` locally. So if you close the powershell session and open a new one with powershell 7, you don't need to login again. You could use [`Get-AzContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azcontext?view=azps-6.3.0) for a quick check, then get the token again, it works fine on my side.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joy. Get-AzContext will work only if user is ad connected. what if user is not connected to ad?

Comment: @ArvindSingh Yes, you're right, as the powershell essentially uses `/organizations` endpoint in the request url. If the user account is not in AAD, you could invite it to an AAD, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal#add-a-new-guest-user-in-azure-ad).

Comment: @ArvindSingh After accepting the invitation and before getting the token, make sure you login with the correct tenant  with `Connect-AzAccount -Tenant <AAD tenant-id>` or use `Set-AzContext -Tenant <AAD tenant-id>` after login. The logged-in AAD should be the one [which the Azure devops Org backed in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops), otherwise the token will not work.

Comment: Hi @Joy thanks again for your valuable comment. I am doing similar thing using ADAL and its working fine with PS5, even after closing PS ISE and reopen again, it does not ask again to reselect/relogin, it automatically use last used logged-in identity. code: ``` $PromptBehavior = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Auto;$PlatformParameters = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters -ArgumentList $PromptBehavior; $result = $ctx.AcquireTokenAsync($adoResourceId, $clientId, [Uri]::new($replyUri),$PlatformParameters).Result; ```

Comment: I can not invite and add, If the user account is not in AAD. can not use Connect-AzAccount and azcontext

Comment: @ArvindSingh Really? So the user is not in any AAD tenant? What's the value of `$adoResourceId` in your script? Could you decode the access token with http://jwt.io/ and add the screenshot to your question(hide your privacy information)?